# How can I return a sorted table index as a string?

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, lua-table

I'm very unfamiliar working with LUA and LUA tables.

The example I would like to provide is that I want to know the name of the person who has the least amount of money in his/her bank account:

```
BankAccount = {}
BankAccount["Tom"] = 432
BankAccount["Henry"] = 55
BankAccount["Kath"] = 875

table.sort(BankAccount)
print("BankAccount Element at index 1 is ", BankAccount[1])
```

Goal: I would like for it to return the string "Henry".

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to structure the table in such a way for it to return the string based on a value. I've also seen people do:

```
BankAccount = {
    {"Tom", 432},
    {"Henry", 55},
    {"Kath", 875},
}
```

So I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort the first table, as it's a hash table that doesn't have any specific order, but you can sort the second one if you provide a sorting function:

```
BankAccount = {
    {"Tom", 432},
    {"Henry", 55},
    {"Kath", 875},
}
table.sort(BankAccount, function(a, b) return a[2] < b[2] end)
print(BankAccount[1][1]) -- should print Henry
```

`table.sort` takes a function as the second parameter that will receive two values being sorted and needs to return true/false value indicating if the first element needs to go before the second (see [table.sort](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort)).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Paul! Can you explain to me why the first version can't be sorted? A little bit confused by that since I see it as a table of values that should be able to be manipulated... but again not familiar with LUA.

Comment: It's because the first table is a hash table `{ Tom = 432, Henry = 55, ...etc.}`, which doesn't have any particular order. You can use `pairs` to navigate a hash table, but the retrieval order is not predictable; in fact, it's randomized in Lua. So, if you want to get a specific order, you need to store keys in a table, sort them using `table.sort` and then navigate that table with key while retrieving values from the hash table.